Node's queues: order of Check Queue vs IO Queue?
If I understand correctly, in Node, in terms of priority, IO Queue > Check Queue.
But if you run this code:
fs.readFile('./tweets.json', (err, data) => {
  console.log('IO Queue');
});
setImmediate(() => {
  console.log('Check Queue');
});

The result is:
Check Queue
IO Queue

Moreover, if there's an error, the result logs are reversed. Is there something else involved I'm not aware of?

The callback passed to readFile is only queued when the either the file is read or an error occurs. In the case the file is read, this takes some time on the non-JS level, so when node monitors its queues it finds that the IO queue is still empty and goes on with the check queue.
Depending on the error, it might be that the error condition is immediate, like a badly constructed file name. In that case the callback will be placed in the IO queue immediately, and node will find it first.

I get it, because files takes time to read, IO queue might be empty for a while. I see the same thing happens if I call setTimeout(cb, 0) v.s. setTimeout(cb, 1000) - cb will run later in the second case. Now it's the Timer Queue instead of IO Queue, but is that the same behavior?

Yes, same principle.
